# How to create a running total, according to factor, in R?

Tags: r

I am wishing to create a running scoreline margin for sport data. For example, consider my data as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Club = c("O", "H", "H", "O", "H", "O", "O"),
                 TimeOfScore = c("1:30", "2:06", "7:09", "9:09", "11:08", "14:32", "19:11"),
                 Points = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```

In the above, `"df$Club==O"` represents the opposition's score, whilst `df$Club=="H"`. The column `df$TimeOfScore` represents when the score occurs. I wish to know a running scoreline of how many points the opposition is ahead or below of the home team.

My anticipated output would be:

```
df$Margin <- c(-1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, -3)
```

This output is based on how many points ahead or below the opposition team are compared to the home team. For example, the opposition team score 1 point at 1:30 (1 minute, 30 seconds), into the game. The corresponding margin at that point in time is -1 or the home team down by one point. In the next occurrence, the home team score 3 points and are then 2 points ahead in the margin.

How would I please go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df$Margin = with(df, cumsum(ifelse(Club == "H", Points, -Points)))
# df
# Club Points Margin
# 1    O      1     -1
# 2    H      3      2
# 3    H      1      3
# 4    O      2      1
# 5    H      2      3
# 6    O      3      0
# 7    O      3     -3
```

Answer (score 3):

#### In words

You can tests if the `Club` is "H" or "O", which will give a TRUE or FALSE.

You can then use the fact that `T == 1` and `F == 0` to add 1 to it.

Then you use this result to subset the vector `c(-1, 1)`, then multiply this value by the `points`.

Then find the cumulative sum, and there's your answer.

#### In code

```
df$Margin <- cumsum(c(-1, 1)[(df$Club == "H")+1] * df$Points)

df
#   Club Points Margin
# 1    O      1     -1
# 2    H      3      2
# 3    H      1      3
# 4    O      2      1
# 5    H      2      3
# 6    O      3      0
# 7    O      3     -3
```